# Using line Path generator for tree Layout

Tags: d3.js

Wanted to use my own custom path generator instead of diagonal path generator.[image: **enter image description here**]

I drew three lines between two nodes.

1)One vertical line from the source to the midpoint of the two nodes.
2)One horizontal line from the midpoint to the x cordinate of the target node.
3)the third line to the target

The issue with this process is the first line is getting overwritten leading to a bolder shade of line.

Another issue is the transitions when the nodes are collapsed and expanded. Is there any way to solve these two issues.

Comment: link.transition().duration(duration)
          .attr("d",function(d){
           
           var data = [ {x:d.source.x,y:d.source.y},{x:d.source.x,y:Math.floor((d.target.y+d.source.y)/2)}
           ,{x:d.target.x,y:Math.floor((d.target.y+d.source.y)/2)},{x:d.target.x,y:d.target.y}];
           return line(data);
          }); var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { 
         return d.x; }
        )
        .y(function(d) {
         return d.y; 
         })
        .interpolate("linear");

Comment: the above code is used for generating the paths.

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution to this problem.